# BEFORE UPDATE works fine but BEFORE INSERT does not trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

This is regarding a library. I'm trying to create a trigger that takes the title of the book and store it in the enitity containing the unique copy of the book.

My trigger works fine in BEFORE UPDATE but nothing happens (and no errors either) in BEFORE INSERT.

This is the BEFORE UPDATE trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `copies_BEFORE_UPDATE_title` BEFORE UPDATE ON `copies` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE v_title VARCHAR(254);
    DECLARE v_BorD INT;
    
    SET v_BorD = (SELECT copies.artNr FROM copies
    WHERE barcode = NEW.barcode);
    IF(v_BorD IS NULL)THEN SET v_BorD = 0;
    END IF;
    
    IF(v_BorD = 0)
    THEN
        SELECT books.bTitle INTO v_title FROM books
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.isbn = books.isbn AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    ELSE
        SELECT dvds.dTitle INTO v_title FROM dvds
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.artNr = dvds.artNr AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    END IF;
    
    SET NEW.Title = v_title;
END
```

The BEFORE INSERT is identical except for line 1 for obvious reasons.
The attribute barcode is the primary key but it is not auto-incremental, it is typed manually when inserted.

Here is MRE or an troubleshoot-database as requested:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `libraryfortesting` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ /*!80016 DEFAULT ENCRYPTION='N' */;
USE `libraryfortesting`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.26, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: libraryfortesting
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.26

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `books`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `books`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `isbn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bTitle` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `books`
--

LOCK TABLES `books` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `books` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `books` VALUES ('0007203543','The fellowship of the ring');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `books` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `copies`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `copies`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `copies` (
  `barcode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(245) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`barcode`),
  KEY `fk_isbn_idx` (`isbn`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_isbn` FOREIGN KEY (`isbn`) REFERENCES `books` (`isbn`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `copies`
--

LOCK TABLES `copies` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `copies` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `copies` VALUES ('123456789012','0007203543',NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `copies` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `copies_BEFORE_INSERT_title` BEFORE INSERT ON `copies` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE v_title VARCHAR(254);
    DECLARE v_BorD INT;
    
    SET v_BorD = (SELECT copies.artNr FROM copies
    WHERE barcode = NEW.barcode);
    IF(v_BorD IS NULL)THEN SET v_BorD = 0;
    END IF;
    
    IF(v_BorD = 0)
    THEN
        SELECT books.bTitle INTO v_title FROM books
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.isbn = books.isbn AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    ELSE
        SELECT dvds.dTitle INTO v_title FROM dvds
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.artNr = dvds.artNr AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    END IF;
    
    SET NEW.title = v_title;
END */;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `copies_BEFORE_UPDATE_title` BEFORE UPDATE ON `copies` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE v_title VARCHAR(254);
    DECLARE v_BorD INT;
    
    SET v_BorD = (SELECT copies.artNr FROM copies
    WHERE barcode = NEW.barcode);
    IF(v_BorD IS NULL)THEN SET v_BorD = 0;
    END IF;
    
    IF(v_BorD = 0)
    THEN
        SELECT books.bTitle INTO v_title FROM books
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.isbn = books.isbn AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    ELSE
        SELECT dvds.dTitle INTO v_title FROM dvds
        JOIN copies
        WHERE copies.artNr = dvds.artNr AND barcode = NEW.barcode;
    END IF;
    
    SET NEW.Title = v_title;
END */;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2022-02-02 19:03:58
```

Thank you for your time, with or without solution <3

Comment: debugging trgeers without data is nearly impossible, if there are not some basic errors, please add a [mre] as dbfiddle so hat we can see. But i doubt tha NEw.barcode extsists so that the select will not get any records

Comment: @nbk Thank you, I will start creating one now. But yes, the issue has to be NEW.barcode because it doesn't exist before the insert, but is rather a part of the insert. Maybe my question should be more like "how to change a value of an attribute for the specific INSERT"...

Comment: *the issue has to be NEW.barcode because it doesn't exist before the insert* This is a value to be inserted into the table, it cannot "doesn't exist".